# Edit of page with captcha requires solving captcha?

Tags: captcha

I just added a captcha to a page and it seems that the users with edit permission have to solve the captcha in order to edit/save the page. Is this normal behavior?  Is there a setting that will allow for editing w/o having to solve the captcha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the assumption that you're using the [CAPTCHA](https://www.drupal.org/project/captcha) module there is a permission called [Skip CAPTCHA](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/captcha/tree/captcha.module?h=7.x-1.x#n117) you should configure for your editor's roles to skip it.